# Perl 1 liner: Can print unicode input but regex not working; fancy word boundaries

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, stdout, stdin

Suppose I have (in Bash):

```
txt="На берегу пустынных волн
Стоял он, дум великих полн,
И вдаль глядел."
```

If I pipe this to Perl, I can print no problem:

```
$ echo "$txt" | perl -lnE 'say "$_"'
На берегу пустынных волн
Стоял он, дум великих полн,
И вдаль глядел.
```

But I am having issues with various regex on this text. Suppose I add the new [Fancy Word Boundaries](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2016/06/perl-v5-22-adds-fancy-unicode-word-boundaries/):

```
$ echo "$txt" | perl -lnE 'while (/\b{wb}(.+?)\b{wb}/g) { print "\"$1\"" }'
"–"
"ù"
"–"
"∞"
" "
"–"
"±"
"–µ—"
"Ä"
...
# junk characters...
```

The word boundaries are not working and the input characters are altered.

(If I change the regex to `/\b{wb}(.+)\b{wb}/g` the output is the same as the first. The `(.+)` consumes the entire line.)

I can fix these issues with the addition of the [-CASD](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) command line switch and the fancy word boundaries work as designed:

```
$ echo "$txt" | perl -CSAD  -lnE 'while (/\b{wb}(.+?)\b{wb}/g) { print "\"$1\"" }'
"На"
" "
"берегу"
" "
"пустынных"
" "
"волн"
"Стоял"
" "
"он"
","
" "
"дум"
" "
"великих"
" "
"полн"
","
"И"
" "
"вдаль"
" "
"глядел"
"."
```

**The question:** The `-CASD` switches in [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) seems to imply that the unicode features enabled are for `stdin` and `stdout` input streams. There is no mention of any internal differences that would change a regex. Since I can read and print unicode in the first case, why does adding `-CASD` change the regex?

```
$ perl -v
This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 0 (v5.28.0) built for darwin-thread-multi-2level
```

Comment: *"I can fix that with the addition of the `-CASD` command line switch"* Your new command works because you have used `.+?` instead of `.+`. The output of both commands is correct.

Comment: It's best not to habitually use "magic" command line options for any utility. In `perl -lanE`, `-a` unnecessarily autosplits each line into `@F`, which you never use, and `-l` strips the record separator from each line and puts it back on output, which is unnecessary if you're using `say`. Just `perl -nE` is all you need.

Comment: I didn't claim that the output was correct whatever you do to the regex pattern. I am pretty sure that perl is behaving correctly and you are wrong to say *"the word boundaries are not working"*.

Comment: @Borodin: Eliminating `l` in the command line switches will result in the output being double spaced with `say`.

Comment: @Borodin: *I am pretty sure that perl is behaving correctly and you are wrong to say "the word boundaries are not working"* Please try the examples. choroba is correct - the `-CASD` causes the input stream to be decoded from the UTF-8 and the regex works as intended. Without that, it is just raw bytes and the `/\b{wb}` then has no meaning on raw bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case, you aren't reading and printing unicode, you're reading and printing UTF-8. For Perl, these strings consist of bytes (octets), not characters, so it can find word boundaries in the middle of a multibyte sequence. See [perlunicode](http://p3rl.org/perlunicode) for details.

Comment: Are you sure? Certainly `\b` will misbehave if it sees a UTF-8-encoded string, but it looks like most of the blame is on the use of `/\b(.+?)\b/g` instead of `/\b{wb}(.+)\b{wb}/g`.

Comment: @Borodin: I changed the regex to `/\b(.+?)\b/g` to show the issues in the post. Please actually try the examples.

Comment: @dawg: I wrote my comment to **choroba** as I am particularly interested in what he has to say. I'm not too disappointed to have no reply as it's 2:40am where he is, and I'm happy to wait a while to see if he wants to respond. It would have been much better if you had *added* another test to your post, as editing the existing information renders all comments obsolete. It's now very unclear as the edits to your question are different from what you say you changed. I apologise, but I'm unable to do any tests myself as I have only a phone and a tablet to work with for the next day or two.

Comment: @Borodin: Omitting the `?` consumes the whole lines. Using `\b{wb}` doesn't help, as Perl still sees the octets, and their membership in word/non-word classes makes no sense with respect to the characters composed of them.

Answer (score -1):

> Since I can read and print unicode in the first case, why does adding `-CASD` change the regex?

That command-line option just makes perl decode incoming data as if it were UTF-8-encoded, and re-encode outgoing data as UTF-8

Just reading text and printing the same text with the same encoding doesn't require the stream to be decoded and re-encoded, as the byte sequence is already encoded correctly

If the input were, say, Windows-1255-encoded (Hebrew), while the output needed to be UTF-8-encoded, then the data would need to be *decoded* first to a character string and then *encoded* to a UTF-8 byte sequence

It is only when the input and output require exavtly the same encoding, and there is no need to process the input as a character string, that the decoding and encoding can be dispensed with